# How do I disable key-chord-mode in the minibuffer?

Tags: minibuffer, key-chord-mode

`key-chord-mode` is useful, but I don't need it to work in the minibuffer. How do I disable it in the minibuffer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add this code in your init file:

```
(defun disable-key-chord-mode ()
  (set (make-local-variable 'input-method-function) nil))

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook #'disable-key-chord-mode)
```