# How do you disable the buffer end/beginning warnings in the minibuffer?

Tags: minibuffer, buffer-local, warning

I see that I can do something like [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2108/2685):

```
(defun limit-warnings ()
  (set (make-local-variable 'warning-minimum-level) 'fatal))

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'disable-warnings)
```

(Sorry for syntax errors; I'm not very familiar with Lisp and the above is just an example.)

How do I combine that with [warning options](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Warning-Options.html) to disable warnings from only the minibuffer? (For example, the minibuffer doesn't need to tell me that I've hit the end of the buffer or that the `M-x:` prompt string is read-only.)

I tried `describe-variable` with `warning-minimum-level` and there was no such variable defined.

Comment: You want to look at **the functions *that use*** `line-move-visual` or `line-move-1` or `line-move` -- within the library `simple.el` -- the error message occurs because the optional argument of `noerror` is **not** being used to suppress the error message.  However, some functions depend upon that signal error to halt an ongoing function -- e.g., multiple-cursors mode depends upon that signal error to prevent a never ending loop.

Comment: @lawlist: Please post that as an an answer, which the OP can perhaps then accept.

Comment: Why hasn't `(setq warning-minimum-level :emergency)` been suggested as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very similar to the question [Is there a way to disable the “buffer is read-only” warning?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19742/2355), so a very similar answer seems appropriate.

You can disable these messages by setting [`command-error-function`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Processing-of-Errors.html#Processing-of-Errors) to a function that ignores signals `buffer-read-only`, `beginning-of-buffer`, and `end-of-buffer`.

```el
(defun my-command-error-function (data context caller)
  "Ignore the buffer-read-only, beginning-of-buffer,
end-of-buffer signals; pass the rest to the default handler."
  (when (not (memq (car data) '(buffer-read-only
                                beginning-of-buffer
                                end-of-buffer)))
    (command-error-default-function data context caller)))

(setq command-error-function #'my-command-error-function)
```

(Tested using GNU Emacs 24.5.1.)

Comment: I believe a big warning disclaimer is in order? Would this cause the `M-0 C-x e` executions to go on in inf loop? I use that to keep repeating a kmacro from the current point to the end of the buffer (technically until there's an error).

Comment: @KaushalModi: Nope. (Try for yourself: `C-x ( C-n C-x ) M-0 C-x e` would do.) `command-error-function` is called when there is an **unhandled** signal, and since `end-of-buffer` is caught by the kmacro execution code, `command-error-function` is not called.

Comment: @KaushalModi: Hmm. I was wrong. It *is* called, but it still does not cause an infinite loop, it seems. (The old comment should remain as a reminder for me to test things before speaking up.)

Comment: @KaushalModi: it turns out that [`cmd_error()`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/99fa8c3dbf333f1e3fa7d6449d4b4428ce439ce1/src/keyboard.c#L941) in `keyboard.c` sets `executing-kbd-macro` to `nil` before `command-error-function` is called, so kmacros are stopped on error *no matter what you do*.